# How do you center text in a header in html <div>?

Tags: html, text, alignment

I can't seem to get the html and style coding right.  I can center the text horizontally in html, but I can't get it centered vertically.  I am probably missing something simple.  This is my first time on stack overflow.  I hope that I do everything right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .Header>p {
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: black;
      padding-top=20px;
      color: white;
      top: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="Header">
    <p>This text will be vertically aligned</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure your div is set to a height where you can notice the vertical alignment, and also the display is set to **table-cell**

```css
.Header{
  height:200px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<div class="Header">
  <p>This text will be vertically aligned</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 100px;` to your css:

```
  .Header > p {  height: 100px; 
                 text-align: center; 
                 background-color:black; 
                 padding-top=20px;color:white; 
                 top: 50px;
                line-height: 100px;
   }
```

Make the line-height equal to the height of your div.